# Daily time limitations from Google Scripts in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form ready but I wish to set a time limit on it so that it goes live everyday from 8am (it starts accepting responses) to 5pm (it stops accepting responses). I managed to find something close to what I wanted here https://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-google-forms/20707/.

I am not a programmer with no knowledge of JS but have a little knowledge on C++ (mandatory university unit).
I have tried to tweak the sourced code to my wishes by researching online.
here is my script in google scripts.

```
function oc() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('openForm')
     .timeBased()
     .everyDays(1)
     .atHour(8)
     .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('closeForm')
     .timeBased()
     .everyDays(1)
     .atHour(16)
     .create();
}

function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  deleteTriggers_();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample script?

### Flow :

1. In order to launch `oc()`, please at first, run `initTrigger()`. By this, `oc()` is launched at AM 0:00 every day. Please at first run this only one time.

   - After `initTrigger()` was run, you can confirm this trigger on your script editor.
2. When `oc()` is launched at AM 0:00, existing triggers for launching `openForm()` and `closeForm()` are removed.
3. And then, the triggers for launching `openForm()` and `closeForm()` are installed as new trigger. At this time, the trigger days for `openForm()` and `closeForm()` are today's AM 8:00 and PM 5:00, respectively.

### Scripts :

```
function initTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('oc').timeBased().atHour(0).everyDays(1).create();
}

function oc() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function(e){
    if(e.getHandlerFunction() == "openForm" || e.getHandlerFunction() == "closeForm") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(e)
    }
  });

  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(8);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

  time.setHours(17);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().at(time).create();
}

function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  // deleteTriggers_();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have understood quite a fair bit of what you coded and mended and yes, it answers my query. I have put it on the script and ran the trigger as you asked.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for the solution. I am using your script and flow. but I observed that my Form is opened all time. The above not working for me.

Comment: ＠mohitji About your question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I am using your script and flow. but I observed that my Form is opened all time. The above not working for me.` I cannot understand your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you post your question as new question by including more information for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?