# Trying to limit responses to Google form to a daily time frame

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form on which i would like to limit the responses to a certain time frame every day. I only want to accept responses between 0800 and 2000, 7 days a week. I have used the code written in a previous answer to this question by my form remains closed to responses. I have attached a copy of my Script and a link to the form.

```
function initTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("Timer").timeBased().atHour(0).everyDays(1).create();
}

function Timer() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function(e){
    if(e.getHandlerFunction() == "openForm" || e.getHandlerFunction() == "closeForm") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(e)
    }
  });

  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(8);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

  time.setHours(20);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().at(time).create();
}

function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  //deleteTriggers_();
}
```

[Test form with script](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1J4sP9ZjVURpwwr8R6VA-LkwhX_V8TokwsRelvo6DaxU/edit)

Comment: Hi. I'm just looking at older questions, like yours, that don't have any comments or answers. Did you resolve the "problem" with your form, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: This one did not get fixed unfortunately.

Comment: Hi. You've adapted Tanaike's answer from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45527100/1330560) - right? He's a very good operator, so that ought to be a good solution. I can only see three differences: main function name (oc vs Timer), double quotes ("Timer") vs single quotes ('oc'), and increased availability from 5pm (17) to 8pm (20). Did you also follow his "Flow" instructions?